# PHPStorm no encuentra los usos de sus funciones en JS

Tags: javascript, ide

Buenos días. No es un problema en si, porque lo puedo buscar por otros medios, pero los que sois usuarios de PHPStorm (yo estoy en la versión 2017.2.3), ¿os sucede que el IDE no es capaz de encontrar los usos de las funciones en JavaScript? Mientras que en PHP dicha funcionalidad va de maravilla, en ficheros JS no es capaz de encontrarlos ni siquiera en el mismo fichero.

Las declaraciones por ejemplo, no tiene ningún problema, pero a la inversa ya digo, no funciona.

He estado pajareando en el mar de opciones de personalización que ofrece PHPStorm y no me ha parecido encontrar nada así. ¿Este comportamiento sería normal o me falta por configurar o definir algo?

Un saludo y gracias a todos

Comment: No tengo problemas...te refieres a `show usages of function xxxx`? en mac `cmd+ left  mouse click`

Comment: Si, exactamente. Yo lo manejo desde Windows, y ya dicho, para PHP funciona perfectamente, pero para JS no

Comment: Pues lo dicho... lo acabo de actualizar a 2017.2.3 y funciona perfectamente (en mac)...prueba de desinstalar y instalarlo de nuevo... suerte y saludos

Comment: No se, ya digo que solo es para JS que no me funciona. Es algo extraño aunque bueno, no es un verdadero problema. Tan solo era la comodidad